# Why does the Remove Button Stop Working On Elements That Were Created Through Functions? | Javascript & HML

Tags: javascript, html

**Question**

I have created a cart, where you can add or remove items. If you remove an item, the price is taken away from the total price calculation: and more importantly the element that is displayed as a cart item is removed from the Cart.

When many cart items are added to the cart, for some reason only the very first cart item can be removed. All subsequent remove buttons do not work.

I will do my best to provide a minimal sample:

```js
if(document.readyState == 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}


const BasketTotal = document.getElementsByClassName('basket-total')[0];


function ready(){
    let removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-btn');
    for(let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++){
        let button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }
    let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart-btn');
    for(let i=0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++){
        let button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}

function purchaseClicked(){
    alert('Thank you for your purchase');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    while(cartItems.hasChildNodes()){
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event){
    let buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event){
    let button = event.target;
    let cartItem = button.parentElement;
    let title = cartItem.getElementsByClassName('dom-title')[0].innerText;
    let price = cartItem.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText;
    addItemToCart(title, price);
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price){
    let basketItem = document.createElement('div');
    //CartItems was changed to cartCards
    let cartCards = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    let cartItemNames = cartCards.getElementsByClassName('cart-domain');
    for(let i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++){
        if(cartItemNames[i].innerText == title){
            alert('This item is already added to the cart');
            return;
        }
    }
    let cartContents = `
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="cart-card">
    <h5 class="cart-domain">${title}<span style="color: gray">.crypto</span></h5>
     <hr style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
    
     <p class="cart-text">No recurring fees. This domain will never expire. You will own the domain outright.</p>
     <br>
     <br>
     <button class="cart-purchase">Buy it now</button>
     <div class="price-cart-item">
         <br>
         <br>
         <p>
             Price: <span class="cart-item-price">${price}</span>
         </p>
         <br>
         <button class="remove-btn">Remove <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    
     </div>
     <p class="cart-text">Renewal Cost: $0.00</p>
    </div>`;

    basketItem.innerHTML = cartContents;
    cartCards.append(basketItem);
    cartCards.getElementsByClassName('remove-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    
}


function updateCartTotal(){
    let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    let cartCards = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-card');
    let total = 0;
    for(let i =0; i < cartCards.length; i++){
        let cartCard = cartCards[i];
        let priceElement = cartCard.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-price')[0];
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')); 
        total += price;
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
    let commasAdded = total.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementsByClassName('basket-total')[0].innerText = '$' + commasAdded;
}
```

```html
<!--Products for sale -->

<div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">happy</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                       
                    <div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">exchange</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">bestdadever</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    
<!--Cart-->


<div class="cart-total-text">
                        <p>Your Items</p>
                        <p>Total: <span class="basket-total"></span></p>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="cart-cards">
                      
                    
                   </div>
```

This would really help me out if you can identify why the remove buttons are only working some of the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `ready()` function only once when the document is ready. I made a  little change in your code and put the `ready()` function into your `addToCartClicked(event)` function too. So every time you click the add to cart button, you create the remove buttons, and then you add the event listeners.

Hope it helps you.

```js
if(document.readyState == 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}


const BasketTotal = document.getElementsByClassName('basket-total')[0];


function ready(){
    let removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-btn');
    for(let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++){
        let button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }
    let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart-btn');
    for(let i=0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++){
        let button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}

function purchaseClicked(){
    alert('Thank you for your purchase');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    while(cartItems.hasChildNodes()){
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event){
    let buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event){
    let button = event.target;
    let cartItem = button.parentElement;
    let title = cartItem.getElementsByClassName('dom-title')[0].innerText;
    let price = cartItem.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText;
    addItemToCart(title, price);
    updateCartTotal();
    // HERE
    ready();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price){
    let basketItem = document.createElement('div');
    //CartItems was changed to cartCards
    let cartCards = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    let cartItemNames = cartCards.getElementsByClassName('cart-domain');
    for(let i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++){
        if(cartItemNames[i].innerText == title){
            alert('This item is already added to the cart');
            return;
        }
    }
    let cartContents = `
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="cart-card">
    <h5 class="cart-domain">${title}<span style="color: gray">.crypto</span></h5>
     <hr style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
    
     <p class="cart-text">No recurring fees. This domain will never expire. You will own the domain outright.</p>
     <br>
     <br>
     <button class="cart-purchase">Buy it now</button>
     <div class="price-cart-item">
         <br>
         <br>
         <p>
             Price: <span class="cart-item-price">${price}</span>
         </p>
         <br>
         <button class="remove-btn">Remove <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    
     </div>
     <p class="cart-text">Renewal Cost: $0.00</p>
    </div>`;

    basketItem.innerHTML = cartContents;
    cartCards.append(basketItem);
    cartCards.getElementsByClassName('remove-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    
}


function updateCartTotal(){
    let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-cards')[0];
    let cartCards = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-card');
    let total = 0;
    for(let i =0; i < cartCards.length; i++){
        let cartCard = cartCards[i];
        let priceElement = cartCard.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-price')[0];
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')); 
        total += price;
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
    let commasAdded = total.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementsByClassName('basket-total')[0].innerText = '$' + commasAdded;
}
```

```html
<!--Products for sale -->

<div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">happy</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                       
                    <div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">exchange</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div class="domain-item">
                        <p class="domain-aspect domain-title"><strong class="linked"><span class="dom-title">bestdadever</span><span style="color: #1a6db7">.com</span></span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   <span class="item-price">$100,000</span></p>
                        <button class="domain-aspect add-to-cart-btn">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    
<!--Cart-->


<div class="cart-total-text">
                        <p>Your Items</p>
                        <p>Total: <span class="basket-total"></span></p>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="cart-cards">
                      
                    
                   </div>
```